# Javascript to change multiple <select> to same option chosen in first

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

First time posting so I apologize for any etiquette errors.

I am trying to make an html page to replace a flash page for inspections of building sites.  The current flash changes several of the fields to the same option as the Overall rating. The html I have so far is as follows:

```
<label for="inspectDate">
    Inspection Date:
</label>
<br>
<input type="date" id="inspectDate" name="inspectDate" class="xsmall">
<p>
    <label for="overallRating">Overall Rating
        <br>
        <select id="overallRating" name="overallRating">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="fair">Fair</option>
            <option value="poor">Poor</option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <label for="generalAppearance">General Appearance
                <br>
                <select id="generalAppearance" name="generalAppearance">
                    <option value="null"></option>
                    <option value="good">Good</option>
                    <option value="fair">Fair</option>
                    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
                    <option value="n/a">N/A</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </p>
    </label>
</p>
```

I know very little js and am teaching myself as I go.  If someone can help me with this first one I can extrapolate across as many select fields as I need to

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Have the first ddl's value equal to the 2nd ddl?

Comment: Please explain want to achieve as end result, describe. And welcome to the new journey.

Comment: Trying to make all subsequent <select> fields copy the first whenever the first is changed.  So if I choose "Good" on the first select, it will choose that in all subsequent fields I specify.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified demo:

```js
let bubu = document.querySelectorAll('.bubu');

// In JS count starts from 0. bubu[0] — the first element of the colletion.

bubu[0].value = undefined;
bubu[0].addEventListener('change', function(){
  for( let i = 1; i < bubu.length; i++ ){
    bubu[i].selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    // `this` - the element, which fired the function. The same as `bubu[0]`
  }
});
```

```css
select { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<select class="bubu">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select> - Main
<hr><br><br><br><br>
<select class="bubu">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>N/A</option>
</select> - First
<hr>
<select class="bubu">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>N/A</option>
</select> - Second
```

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?  This did it.  I didn't even need to change the js at all, just made them all class="bubu"  Thanks!

Comment: What might I change to make choosing the first, blank option, clear all the fields?  As of right now if you pick something in one of the lower fields, then pick the blank field in the first option, it will not clear the lower field.  If you then choose, say, "good" in the first field, then choose the blank one, it will clear them.  Is there an easy way to make choosing the blank field in the first one clear all of the others?

Comment: Added default `bubu[0].value = undefined;` which will cause to fire the `change` event at the first option-choosing. Or, you may replace the `change` with `click` event... but it will reset all chosen options each time the `0` element was clicked.